# How do I change draggable state of AnnotationView at specific moment?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want change draggable state from YES to NO when user pressed the button.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view.draggable = NO;`

If you need to get a reference to your annotationView, you can do so with `MKMapView viewForAnnotation:`:

```
MKAnnotationView *view = [self.map viewForAnnotation:self.annotation];
view.draggable = NO;
```